# git clone on nfs share not working(Permission denied)

Tags: git, nfs

I'm using a nfs storage server for my debian home directory.

```
server:
/home/nfs 192.168.0.0/16(rw,sync,fsid=1,crossmnt,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
client:
192.168.1.8:/home/nfs on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,relatime,sync,vers=4.2,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.1.9,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.1.8)
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when I use `git clone`, it have a file permissions. The output line is:

```
/mnt/test $ git clone https://github.com/nelu/rutorrent-filemanager
Cloning into 'rutorrent-filemanager'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 487, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (487/487), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (297/297), done.
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/mnt/test/rutorrent-filemanager/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
```

I use `sudo git clone` can work fine.

```
/mnt/test $sudo git clone https://github.com/nelu/rutorrent-filemanager
Cloning into 'rutorrent-filemanager'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 487, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (487/487), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (297/297), done.
remote: Total 569 (delta 326), reused 341 (delta 187), pack-reused 82
Receiving objects: 100% (569/569), 252.76 KiB | 50.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (340/340), done.
Checking out files: 100% (63/63), done.
```

but `getfacl` of the directory `/mnt/test` shows the following output:

```
/mnt/test $ getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: fcying
# group: fcying
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

So actually there should be no permission problems, my user has all permissions on the directory. So is there something permission-related that I am missing? 
Or is this a NFS-related problem?
how can I solve this?

git version 2.20.1

client os: Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: What version of Git are you using?

Comment: git version 2.20.1  os:Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u2 (2019-11-11) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Would that persist with git 2.24.1?

Comment: I test `git version 2.24.1` by use linuxbrew. it's the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering any Git version seems to exhibit the issue, you might need to check the drivers, as [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195848/7490) (which was about ntfs though, but can give some ideas).

Check also:

- [`/var/log/syslog`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/372341/7490) for other troubleshooting messages.
- [Debian FileSystem mount options](https://wiki.debian.org/FileSystem)
- [Debian NFS versions](https://wiki.debian.org/NFS)

The [OP fcying](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8273887/fcying) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59541476/git-clone-on-nfs-share-not-workingpermission-denied/59546044?noredirect=1#comment105275780_59546044):

> I saw nfs server `/var/log/syslog`: it had a nfs crash.
>   After I restart nfs server, it works fine.

Comment: tks, I saw nfs server `/var/log/syslog`, it have a nfs crash.after I restart nfs server, it work fine.

Comment: @fcying Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.